# Show the users that I liked using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using Laravel, and I would like to create a `like` and `dislike` system, so a `user` can `like` one to many more `users`.

I already have a table called `Users` (default by Laravel), now I have created another table called `favorite_user` with `id`, `user_id` and `liked_the_user.`

How can I get all the `users` that a `user` already liked? Is my table correct or should I change something?

All what I want to do is add `like` and show the people I `liked`. I don't know how to make this relationship since I am new to Laravel.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a pivot table there so a Many to Many relationship is what you need to setup. You will need to pass some additional arguments since the naming won't fit with convention.

User Model:

```
// users the user has liked
public function liked()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'favorite_user', 'user_id', 'liked_the_user');
}

// users who like the user
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'favorite_user', 'liked_the_user', 'user_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function liked(Request $request)
{
    // get liked users for current user
    $liked = $request->user()->liked;

    // get liked users for an arbitrary user
    $liked = User::findOrFail(...)->liked;

    ...
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) - `belongsToMany`

Comment: thank you,  what should i do to have a naming convention

Comment: @DeveloperDeveloper you can't fully follow convention for this table because you can't have 2 fields named `user_id` so at the very least one of the key fields has to override the convention ... also to follow convention the table name would become less meaningful, `user_user`

Comment: do you have any suggestion to have system structure please :)

Comment: how can i call the liked method in my controller ?

Comment: how can i access the pivot data ( users i liked ) thank you :)

Comment: @DeveloperDeveloper added controller example

Comment: i thank you so so so much for your help, my last question please, is how to add new record in a pivot table

Comment: done $user->liked()->attach([1,2,5]);   thank you again